# Download QT 5.12.0 on my Raspberry fails

Tags: qt

I currently have the **5.11.3 Qt Version** on my **Raspberry 3 B+**. For another program, I want to use I need at least **Qt 5.12.0.**

When I try 
`sudo apt-get install qt5-default`
it says that I already downloaded the latest version which is 5.11.3.

I already read in another post, that for the qt5-default package this really is the latest version.

I searched for other ways to download it, but everything seems to be a lot over the top for what I actually need it for... (with cross-compiling etc.)

I really just need this newer version, is there another simple way to download Qt 5.12.0?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to build Qt 5.12.0 yourself as it isn't packaged for your RPi.

A quick google search pointed me these links:

https://github.com/tranter/raspberry-pi-qt-builds

https://www.tal.org/tutorials/building-qt-512-raspberry-pi